# Get ID of a Clicked Link

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below and demo here http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/vp2YN/3/ you can see I need to get the ID attribute of a clicked item and assign it to a variable in Javascript.

Right now the code returns the ID name of the first item, regardless of which item is clicked on.

In the Javascript you can see I have this line commented out...

`var clickedID = this.attr("id");`
when I use that line, I get an error saying: `Object has no method 'attr'`

Please help me get the ID name of the clicked link and assign it to a variable

HTML

```
<a href="#" style="display:block" class="button insertcolumn" id="one_half">2 Columns</a>

<a href="#" style="display:block" class="button insertcolumn" id="one_third">3 Columns</a>

<a href="#" style="display:block" class="button insertcolumn" id="one_fourth">4 Columns</a>​
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
jQuery('.insertcolumn').click(function(){

    var clickedID = jQuery('.insertcolumn').attr("id");
    //var clickedID = this.attr("id");

    alert(clickedID);

});​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/vp2YN/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to reference the one you clicked with the jQuery wrapper!

You want to use

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

To get the id (without traversing the DOM for no reason) you would be better off to just call the object `id`.

```
this.id;
```

But to access the property regardless of the type of attribute and depending on the name of the attribute use the following code.

```
jQuery('.insertcolumn').click(function(){

    var clickedID = $(this).attr('id');


    alert(clickedID);

});​
```

Comment: You don't *always* need to use *all* the jQuery: `var clickedID = this.id;`

Comment: @DavidThomas true but say he calls the attr with a different name? My case will help for that too! Will update answer anyway

Comment: Yes; but otherwise you're needlessly creating a jQuery object and calling a jQuery method. Fair enough it's worth pointing out the `attr()` method (and its uses), but...honestly, I'd always suggest pointing out that jQuery isn't always needed for every DOM interaction. I wasn't, incidentally, suggesting you were wrong in your answer, just that, perhaps, it'd be worth adding a little more info to your answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas i gathered that, which is why i did indeed and will add more to update the answer!